# Не работает код в switch case

Tags: javascript

При вводе в prompt Строчного значения должно выводится (' number is Ba_NaN')
При вводе Числа должно выводится ('OK!')
Проблема в том что при вводе строчного значения в prompt не выводится console.log(' number is Ba_NaN')
Нужно реализовать строго на switch case

```js
let numOrStr = prompt('input number or string');
console.log(numOrStr)

switch (numOrStr) {  // numOrStr === null //
    case null : {
        console.log('вы отменили')
        break;
    }
    case '' : {     // numOrStr.trim() === '' //
        console.log('Empty String');
        break;
    }
    case  isNaN( +numOrStr ) : {   // isNaN( +numOrStr ) //
        console.log(' number is Ba_NaN')
        break;
    }
    default: {
        console.log('OK!')
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробелма-то в чём? Где конкретно не работает и при каких вводных данных?

Comment: слова "не работает" не являются достаточным описанием проблемы.

Comment: При вводе в prompt Строчного значения должно выводится (' number is Ba_NaN') При вводе Числа должно выводится ('OK!') Нужно реализовать строго на switch case

Comment: что должно быть - поняли все и так, а проблема-то в чём? что сейчас не так?

Comment: При вводе строчного значения в prompt  не выводиться console.log(' number is Ba_NaN')

Comment: Потому что идет сравнение `isNaN( +numOrStr )` и `numOrStr` - а они не равны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так ?

```
let numOrStr = prompt('input number or string');
console.log(numOrStr)

switch (true) {
    case (numOrStr === null):
        console.log('ви скасували')
        break
    case (numOrStr.trim() === ''):
        console.log('Empty String')
        break
    case isNaN( +numOrStr):
        console.log(' number is Ba_NaN')
        break
    default:
        console.log('OK!')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`numOrStr` - это строка.

`case`  в конструкции `switch/case` ожидает, что результат сравнения подаваемого значения в `switch()` и значения в `case` даст `true`, **что они равны**. Что в текущем случае явно не возможно, т.к. строка явно не равна результату работы метода `isNaN` (получается сравнение `строка === isNaN(+строка)`).  Получается на вход надо подавать не переменную `numOrStr`, а булево значение `true`

P.S. первый case в любом случае будет бесполезным, а во-втором случае придётся писать `numOrStr === ''`